# How to co_await in a function that returns IAsyncAction?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, coroutine, c++20, c++-winrt

Here's a simple function that reads a file into a textbox:

```cpp
IAsyncAction MainPage::OnOpenAppBarButtonClick(IInspectable const& /*sender*/, RoutedEventArgs const& /*args*/)
{
    FileOpenPicker picker{};
    picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".txt");

    StorageFile storageFile = co_await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (storageFile)
    {
        txtbox().Text(co_await FileIO::ReadTextAsync(storageFile));
    }
}
```

This used to work fine. As I understand, the return type is `IAsyncAction` when we don't really return a value from a coroutine. Today I updated the WinRT plugin, and now it fails with an error:

> error C3773: Use of 'co_await' in this context is a non-conforming extension in C++20

And asks me to use `/await` to compile the code. It does compile and run fine with that compiler switch, but what is non-conforming about the code above and what's the conforming way of writing this function?

Microsoft has a very similar example in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Web.Syndication.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Web::Syndication;

void PrintFeed(SyndicationFeed const& syndicationFeed)
{
    for (SyndicationItem const& syndicationItem : syndicationFeed.Items())
    {
        std::wcout << syndicationItem.Title().Text().c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}

IAsyncAction ProcessFeedAsync()
{
    Uri rssFeedUri{ L"https://blogs.windows.com/feed" };
    SyndicationClient syndicationClient;
    SyndicationFeed syndicationFeed{ co_await syndicationClient.RetrieveFeedAsync(rssFeedUri) };
    PrintFeed(syndicationFeed);
}

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    auto processOp{ ProcessFeedAsync() };
    // do other work while the feed is being printed.
    processOp.get(); // no more work to do; call get() so that we see the printout before the application exits.
}
```

This fails to compile with the same error with `/std:c++latest` (C++20).

The main question is how to write the first example function in a conforming manner.

Comment: I notice your function has neither a `return ...;` nor a `co_return;`. I don't know if that fixes it, but it's UB to not return anything.

Comment: @chris you can't `co_return` from a function that returns `IAsyncAction` as that's the purpose of that type. If you add a `co_return {};` statement, the compiler complains "has no member `return_type`". You can add `co_return;`, but that's like adding `return;` to the end of a function that returns `void`. I don't think it's syntactically valid to add a regular `return` to a coroutine.

Comment: Never mind, I'm dumb and horribly misremembered how C++ handles that.

Comment: Looks like [there was an issue raised about this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/997182/misleading-description-of-c3773-co-await-is-a-non.html) but it was closed as "needs more information". Maybe you can add the missing information and get this thing fixed?

Comment: @RaymondChen I added a complete example from Microsoft documentations, which also fails to compile under C++20.

Comment: Which compiler version and which version of the C++/WinRT Nuget package are you using? C++20 coroutine support has been [added recently](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/676) to C++/WinRT.

Comment: Please check if the C++ Language Standard used in your project is C++ 17.  If not, you need to set property C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard to ISO C++ 17 Standard(/std: c++ 17), because C++/WinRT is an entirely standard modern C++ 17 language projection for Windows Runtime(WinRT) APIs.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I've set the standard to C++20 as C++20 added coroutines and it's mostly backward-compatible with C++17. It does compile fine under C++17

Comment: @IInspectable I am using VS 16.7.5, WinRT extension 2.0.201008.2, cl.exe 19.27.29112, cppwinrt.exe v1.0.190111.3

Comment: That's odd. Are you using cppwinrt.exe v1? That's the version that used to ship as part of the Windows SDK, and has long been replaced with cppwinrt.exe v2 that's part of the Nuget package.

Comment: @IInspectable I actually don't run cppwinrt.exe manually, Visual Studio does. I just checked `cppwinrt.exe` in CMD which showed that result. Possibly that's not what Visual Studio uses. I'll look more into it. My main question isn't about the compiler though, I just want to know how to write the first example in a conforming way.

Comment: @IInspectable C++/WinRT v2.0.201008.2 it is. I can see that one at the top of generated files.

Comment: Ok, that's more reasonable. The code in question looks to be (almost) correct (don't pass references into coroutines, but that's a different issue). I'm just trying to evaluate, whether there are any incompatibilities. Specifically, the VSIX and Nuget package need to agree. The VSIX supplies the project templates that never update when you update the VSIX. The Nuget package provides the code generator that *will* update for existing projects. There have been changes to both with the recent push towards conforming C++ coroutines.

Comment: Does the Microsoft sample compile for a new project created with the most recent VSIX installed? Have you tried with Visual Studio 16.8 Preview 3? Does that change anything? I'd check myself, though I just lost 2 of my dev machines and currently cannot.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT the example still fails with the same error with `/std:c++latest`. Is this a bug in the compiler or is my example (and the MS sample) actually non-conforming?

Comment: This may be a compiler issue. You could submit a feedback ticket by opening the **Help tab** and selecting **Send Feedback**, selecting **Report a Problem** option.